# auto-fill-mode without automatic indentation

Tags: indentation, auto-fill-mode

Is it possible to prevent `auto-fill-mode` from automatically indenting new lines according to the previous?  I would like new lines to begin at column 0 regardless of the previous line's indentation.

Comment: The value of auto-fill-function is mode-specific. In order to dig in further, please tell  its value and the buffer-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want to use `paragraph-indent-text-mode` or `paragraph-indent-minor-mode` which are resp. major and minor modes to use when editing text where paragraphs are separated by having the first line be indented and the rest of the paragraph start in column 0.